# Using HOC to wrap icon inside tooltip component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using a higher order component to wrap icon, the issue is that the tooltip is not shown unless i click on the icon atleast once. Have added two tooltips the first one is w/o hoc and works as expected, unlike 2nd one in which i have to click once after which tooltip is shown.

Can someone please help??

```
function componentGenerator(WrappedComponent) {
  function DynamicComponent(props, ref) {
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  }
  return React.forwardRef(DynamicComponent);
}

const MyIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <IconButton {...props}>
      <Avatar alt="Not working" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"/>
    </IconButton>
  );
});
const MyHoc = componentGenerator(MyIcon);


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tooltip title="Open settings" key="1">
        <IconButton sx={{ p: 0 }}>
          <Avatar alt="Working" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"/>
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>

      <Tooltip title="Open settings" key="2">
        <MyHoc />
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-booth-2wfeq0?file=/src/App.js:515-521

Comment: You're not passing the ref to the child component. From [Tooltip API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tooltip/#props)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official react documentation:](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#:%7E:text=There%20is%20one%20caveat%20to,component%2C%20not%20the%20wrapped%20component.)

> ... ref is not a prop. Like key, it’s handled differently by React

That's why you need to pass in ref additionally to your spread props:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Avatar, IconButton, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

function componentGenerator(WrappedComponent) {
  function DynamicComponent(props, ref) {
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} ref={ref} />;
  }
  return React.forwardRef(DynamicComponent);
}

const MyIcon = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <IconButton {...props} ref={ref}>
      <Avatar alt="Not working" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
    </IconButton>
  );
});
const MyHoc = componentGenerator(MyIcon);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tooltip title="Open settings" key="1">
        <IconButton sx={{ p: 0 }}>
          <Avatar alt="Working" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Tooltip title="Open settings" key="2">
        <MyHoc />
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-gates-nbvebo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark